# Can one or more element of a partition of unity be identically zero?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Probably a silly or obvious question! But for the sake of clarity, let's take the open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ $(-1,1)$ and its open cover given by all the open sets $U_a = (-a,a)$ with $0<a<1$. Such open cover must admit a partition of unity subordinate to it $\sum_a{\rho_a}=1$, but in order for $\sum_a{\rho_a}$ to be a locally finite sum I guess only a subset of the $\rho_a$ elements can be different from zero. For instance, all identically zero but $\rho_1=1$ over $U$ may satisfy the requirement. Is that correct?

Comment: I never thought of that before, but I think the definition allows it.  Kind of useless, though.

Comment: yes probably not the point of a partition of unit, but just to understand all the aspects of the definition. it is required for the support of each $\rho_a$ to be contained in the corresponding $(-a,a)$, but I think we can say that if the support of $\rho_a$ is the empty set it is "contained' in $(-a,a)$.

Comment: $1$ is not in the index set, so there is no $\rho_1$. For each $x$ only finitely many of the values $\rho_a(x)$ are non-zero, but that doesn't imply that any of the $\rho_a$ is identically zero.

Comment: BTW, I've never head it called anything but a "partition of unity."

Comment: @Rob Arthan by $\rho_1$ I meant the constant function $1$ over the interval $(-1,1)$, which is continuous in the manifold $(-1,1)$. if having just $\rho_1=1$ and all identical zero functions for the other intervals is not a valid partition of unit for $(-1,1)$, what could be a valid one? thanks!

Comment: @saulspatz edited in "unity", thanks!

Comment: Yes, but your open cover does not include $(-1 , 1)$. An open cover of a set $X$ that includes $X$ itself does indeed have a very simple partition of unity along the lines you describe. Also *pace* @saulspatz, I think if you actually wanted to exhibit explicitly a partition of unity in your example (with $(-1, 1)$ covered by the $(-a, a)$ wtih $0 < x < 1$) then it would probably be useful (and possibly necessary?) to make all but countably many of the $\rho_a$ identically zero.

Comment: @Rob Arthan thanks I see your point now. thinking of my example again, though, I don't see how I can do an open cover of $(-1,1)$ via open sets of the form $(-a,a)$ without including $(-1,1)$ itself, which, as you said, makes my cover really trivial because I have a set which is an open cover of itself, making the rest  "overabundant" hence potentially nullable. interesting point also regarding countability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say anything with certainty, since definitions of partitions of unity vary somewhat. That said, it is generally allowed that some elements of the partition vanish, in the following sense:

Given an open cover $C=\{U_i\subseteq M:i\in I\}$ of a smooth manifold $M$, one can define a partition of unity subordinate to $C$ to be a collection $(\psi_i\in C^\infty M:i\in I)$ such that $\operatorname{supp}(\psi_i)\subset U_i$, for each $x\in M$ there is a neighborhood of $x$ on which all but finitely many $\psi_i$ vanish, and $\sum_i\psi_i=1$ (this sum being well defined due to local finiteness).

There is nothing in this definition that requires $\psi_i\neq 0$, and, in order for partitions to exist subordinate to *any* open cover, we *must* allow this case. For instance, every manifold is [Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space), so we can find a countable cover of neighborhoods on which $\psi_i$ is locally finite, which implies only countably many $\psi_i$ are nonvanishing, and thus some $\psi_i$ must vanish if the index set $I$ is uncountable. Additionally, all but finitely many $\psi_i$ must vanish on a compact manifold by a similar argument, and so any partition subordinate to an infinite cover of a compact space will likewise have $\psi_i=0$ for all but finitely many $\psi_i$.

Your choice of cover is one such example by the Lindelöf argument, though as noted in the comments the function $1$ is not supported by any element of the cover. One can instead note that, given a POU $\psi_a,a\in(0,1)$ subordinate to your cover, there is by local finiteness a neighborhood $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ of $0$ such on which all but finitely many $\psi_a$ vanish. This means that among the infinitely many $\psi_a$ with $a<\epsilon$, all but finitely many must be identically zero.

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer! however, I still can't understand why the constant function $1$ defined in the open interval $(-1,1)$ is not supported by the interval $(-1,1)$ itself, as an (un)proper subset of itself, so part of an open cover. I think that function is smooth in the manifold $(-1,1)$, no?

Comment: Kajelad and @Rob Arthan I see that now, I believe it is because in my question I have defined $a$ to be strictly less than $1$. Honestly, that was a typo but I believe that written as it is the question is a bit more interesting, as a direct definition of a partition of unity for that open cover seems not immediate. I can't think of such POU off the top of my mind right now!